# express.Router() is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to set up a rest API that runs on my node.js HTTP server.  For regular calls, I want the path to be `/...`, for API calls, I want to use `/API/...`.

From what I can gather from various webpages, including http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html, what I need is something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

/* set up app ... */

router.route('/some/url').get(...).put(...);
app.use('/API', router);
```

For some reason, however, the third line (`var router = ...`) *always* returns `undefined`.  When I debug, I can plainly see that `express.Router()` is a function with no return statement, but does include a bunch of `this.foo` setters.  This makes me think that I should be calling `var router = new express.Router()`, but I can't find *any* documentation to support that claim.

Ideas on what's going wrong?

My project dependencies in my `packages.json` files are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "express": "^3.4.4",
    "express-react-views": "^0.7.1",
    "fluxxor": "^1.5.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^0.12.2"
  }
```

Comment: `express.Router` was [introduced with Express 4.0](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x) (vs. `^3.4.4`). If the function is available at all with Express 3.x, it's an extension being defined by another module.

Comment: I think you are using too old version of express. You try with express 4.x. or just mention `*` and re install the npm package in your local nom_modules package.

Comment: Yup, I updated my packages to the current version, and revised my app.js.  I'll have to do some more work making it functional, but `.Router()` works now.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You may want to add that as an answer so that the OP can give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading your Express JS package may help

```
npm install express@4.13.4 -g
```

OR

```
npm install express@4.13.4 --save-dev
```

OR

```
//Edit your pakage.json
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.13.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must update or migrate your express to 4.#.# . Defenitly you are using a older version, versions 3.x and 2,x are deprecated. Here is a link for the [migration](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib8KeAsI_LAhUD6SYKHdEKDP8QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexpressjs.com%2Fen%2Fguide%2Fmigrating-4.html&usg=AFQjCNFuFcohMUz688EI6enKGNefSDiUEg&sig2=D5u6xKNcP7OU8hv9qePWTA). Also you can use this comands:

to get the last version

> npm install express --save

or

to get the version 4.13.4

> npm install express@4.13.4 --save