# Why is the Router() Express function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, module, undefined

I'm using TypeScript and Express to create an API that follows the principles of Clean Architecture. I separated each route of my application in a folder, and then I import all of them into an `index.ts` file, merging each one inside an unique router and exporting the same. My problem is that the importation of this unique file is returning `undefined`.

I think that is isn't a problem of my code itself, since TypeScript can infer correctly the type of the imported file and doesn't report any error during development. The only error I get just happens when trying to run the code:

> TypeError: `app.use()` requires a middleware function

This is the code snippet that causes the error:

```
// expressInstance.ts --> Imported by the "server.ts" file, where listening the server happens
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { router } from ".."; // File with all the routes

const expressInstance = express();

expressInstance.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
expressInstance.use(express.json());
expressInstance.use(cors());

expressInstance.use(router); // Line where the error appears

export {
    expressInstance
};
```

And this is the code of the imported `router` file:

```
// index.ts
import { Router } from "express";
import { userRouter } from "./user.routes";
import { postRouter } from "./post.routes";

const router = Router();
router.use("/user", userRouter);
router.use("/post", postRouter);

export {
    router
};
```

I read [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465045/express-router-is-returning-undefined) that the `undefined` return used to happen at Express version 3, but I use the `4.17.13` version, so I think this isn't the cause of the problem. In fact, I have no idea what could be. I tried to see the router content by using `console.log(router)` in the `index.ts` file (before being imported by `expressInstance.ts`), but it didn't work, because the code wasn't even executed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883626/typeerror-app-use-requires-middleware-functions?

Comment: @Andy That doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a path to  your `.use()`

e.g:

```
expressInstance.use('/users', router);  // in the case you wanted the router to be for users
```

Comment: Tried with "/v1" and didn't work, but I received a litte different error: `app.use() requires a middleware function but received a undefined`, or something like this. I can't remember exactly.